# How to use window height in css using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- i need to append window height in class  row flush aligncenter popbx.
- i want to append  window height in particular class.

  ```
          var height=$(window).height();
           //height say 1200.
          jQuery('.row flush aligncenter popbx').css({ "height": height + 'px' });;

          if (page > 4)
          {
              $('body').html('<div class="row flush aligncenter popbx" >
          }
  ```
- i have tried to help from  http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript.
- $('body').html(' style="height: 1200px"')

  worked fine but why there is problem in using height variable in html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed your code:

```
if (page > 4) {
     $('body').html('<div class="row flush aligncenter popbx">');
     $('.row.flush.aligncenter.popbx').css({ "height": $(window).height() });;
}
```

1. The .html() was wrong
2. you have to assign css properties after the element is created, not before, because then you're refering to empty object
3. you were referring wrong to `.row.flush.aligncenter.popbx` (missing dots for classnames)
4. no need for +'px'

Comment: The last part can be simply
$('.row.flush.aligncenter.popbx').height($(window).height());

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.row.flush.aligncenter.popbx').css("height",$(window).height());
```

Note : There is no need to add `"px"`

Answer (score 0):

```
    var height=$(window).height()+'px';  
     //height say 1200.


    if (page > 4)
    {
        $('body').html('<div class=\"row flush aligncenter popbx\">');
        $('.row flush aligncenter popbx').css({ "height": height });;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( window ).height();
```